# Template in a Template -- accessing contained type from a template type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I was trying to write a templatized quicksort function. The thought in my head was that I would write a quicksort that can operate on any data structure that has a subscript operator and an order relation on the objects contained within it, so I could do things like

```
quicksort<deque<int> >();
quicksort<vector<string> >();
```

etc.

I started out with a function like

```
template<typename T>
void quicksort(T& list);
```

the problem I immediately ran into was coming up with a function that performs the swap operation which is necessary for sorting. I need to know if the values I'm swapping are strings, chars, ints, whatever so I can make a temporary to perform the swap!

So I need to be able to do something like this (I know this syntax is incorrect, I'm just trying to illustrate what I'm trying to do):

```
template<typename T, typename R>
void quicksort(T<R>& list);
```

so I can know what type of object is contained within T while I'm performing the swap. Clearly this means that T has to be, itself, a template class with a template argument specifying what type it contains but that's not really a big deal.

Is this possible? It seems like it should be. What is this called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the containers have a typedef `value_type` that you can use to get `T`:

```
template <typename ContainerT>
void quicksort(ContainerT& container)
{
    typedef typename ContainerT::value_type ElementT;
    // etc.
}
```

That said, wherever possible, algorithms should be implemented using iterators, to further decouple them from specific container implementations.  For example,

```
template <typename RandomAccessItT>
void quicksort(RandomAccessItT first, RandomAccessItT last)
{
    typedef std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessItT>::value_type ElementT;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: It would be better to define a `container_traits<T>` struct that uses `T::value_type` in the primary template, and specialises for built-in arrays.

Comment: @Peter:  An array is not a container (where "container" means "adheres to the STL or standard library container concepts").  Pointers into an array can be used as iterators, though.  It is better to use iterators.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that in general I should include a typedef for value_type in every container I make from now on, huh?

Comment: @Alexander:  Yes; there's actually a spec for the STL (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html) that defines the interface containers must implement and what the semantics of different types of iterators are.  (To the best of my knowledge, the SGI STL spec that I linked to matches the actual C++ spec close enough to use it for implementing your own containers and such).

Answer (score 2):

If `T` is a proper STL container, you can get the value type with:

`typename T::value_type`

So, for example, if `T` is an `std::vector<std::string>`, then `typename T::value_type` is an `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::swap to swap two values.

Your template function should be like this :

```
template < class ContainterType >
void quicksort( ContainerType &container )
{
 //  ...
}
```